# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The setter 'idUser=' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I am new to the world of programming. I'm trying to develop a flutter app to track shipments.
User permissions can be assigned within the administrator profile.
When selecting a user and the permission to assign, the system returns the following error and I cannot detect what the problem is
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The setter 'idUser=' was called on null
I am using a role model, a user model and a provider.
I appreciate if you can show me where the error is to learn how to solve it.

Rol model

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/user.dart';

Rol rolFromJson(String str) => Rol.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String rolToJson(Rol data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Rol {

  String id;
  String name;
  String image;
  String route;
  String idUser;
  String idRol;
  List<Rol> roles;
  List<Rol> toList = [];
  User user;

  Rol({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.image,
    this.route,
    this.idUser,
    this.idRol,
    this.roles,
    this.user,
  });

  factory Rol.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Rol(
    id: json["id"] is int ? json["id"].toString() : json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    image: json["image"],
    route: json["route"],
    idUser: json["id_user"] ?? "",
    idRol: json["id_rol"] ?? "",
    roles: json["roles"] == null ? [] : List<Rol>.from(json['roles'].map((model) => Rol.fromJson(model))) ?? [],
    user: json['user'] is String ? userFromJson(json['user']) : json['user'] is User ? json['user'] : User.fromJson(json['user'] ?? {}),
  );

  Rol.fromJsonList(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    if (jsonList == null) return;
    jsonList.forEach((item) {
      Rol rol = Rol.fromJson(item);
      toList.add(rol);
    });
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "image": image,
    "route": route,
    "id_user": idUser,
    "id_rol": idRol,
    "roles": roles,
    "user": user,
  };

}
```

Users model

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/rol.dart';

User userFromJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userToJson(User data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class User {

  String id;
  String username;
  String name;
  String lastname;
  String userRol;
  String password;
  String sessionToken;
  String image;
  List<Rol> roles = [];
  List<User> toList = [];

  User({
    this.id,
    this.username,
    this.name,
    this.lastname,
    this.userRol,
    this.password,
    this.sessionToken,
    this.image,
    this.roles
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
    id: json["id"] is int ? json["id"].toString() : json["id"],
    username: json["username"],
    name: json["name"],
    lastname: json["lastname"],
    password: json["password"],
    userRol: json['userRol'],
    sessionToken: json["session_token"] ?? "",
    image: json["image"],
    roles: json["roles"] == null ? [] : List<Rol>.from(json['roles'].map((model) => Rol.fromJson(model))) ?? [],
  );

  User.fromJsonList(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    if (jsonList == null) return;
    jsonList.forEach((item) {
      User user = User.fromJson(item);
      toList.add(user);
    });
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "username": username,
    "name": name,
    "lastname": lastname,
    "password": password,
    "userRol": userRol,
    "session_token": sessionToken,
    "image": image,
    "roles": roles,
  };
}
```

Roles Provider

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/api/environment/environment.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/response_api.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/rol.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/user.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/utils/shared_pref.dart';

class RolesProvider {

  String _url = Environment.API_DELIVERY;
  String _api = 'api/roles';
  BuildContext context;
  User sessionUser;

  Future init(BuildContext context, User sessionUser) {
    this.context = context;
    this.sessionUser = sessionUser;
  }

  Future<List<Rol>> getRoles() async {
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.http(_url, '$_api/getRoles');
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': sessionUser.sessionToken
      };
      final res = await http.get(url, headers: headers);

      if (res.statusCode == 401) { // NO AUTORIZADO
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Sesión expirada');
        new SharedPref().logout(context, sessionUser.id);
      }

      final data = json.decode(res.body);
      Rol rol = Rol.fromJsonList(data);
      return rol.toList;
    } catch(e) {
      print('ERROR: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<ResponseApi> assignRol(Rol rol) async {
    try{
      Uri url = Uri.http(_url, '$_api/assign');
      String bodyParams = json.encode(rol);
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': sessionUser.sessionToken
      };
      final res = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: bodyParams);

      if (res.statusCode == 401) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Sesión expirada');
        new SharedPref().logout(context, sessionUser.id);
      }

      final data = json.decode(res.body);
      ResponseApi responseApi = ResponseApi.fromJson(data);
      return responseApi;
    }
    catch(e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

Assign Page Controller

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/response_api.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/rol.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/user.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/provider/roles_provider.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/provider/users_provider.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/utils/my_snackbar.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/utils/shared_pref.dart';

class AdministratorRolesAssignController {

  BuildContext context;
  Function refresh;

  SharedPref _sharedPref = new SharedPref();

  User user;
  List<User> users = [];
  UsersProvider _usersProvider = new UsersProvider();

  Rol rol;
  List<Rol> roles = [];
  RolesProvider _rolesProvider = new RolesProvider();

  String idUser;
  String idRol;

  Future init(BuildContext context, Function refresh, Rol rol) async {
    this.context = context;
    this.refresh = refresh;
    this.rol = rol;
    user = User.fromJson(await _sharedPref.read('user'));
    _usersProvider.init(context, sessionUser: user);
    _rolesProvider.init(context, user);

    getUsers();
    getRoles();
    refresh();
  }

  void assignRol() async {

    rol.idUser = idUser;
    rol.idRol = idRol;
    await _rolesProvider.assignRol(rol);

        print('Usuario elegido: ${idUser}');
        print('Rol elegido: ${idRol}');
      // }
  }

  void getUsers() async {
    users = await _usersProvider.getAllUsers();
    refresh();
  }

  void getRoles() async {
    roles = await _rolesProvider.getRoles();
    refresh();
  }

}
```

I hope I can learn to solve the problem.
The idea is to be able to save the information sent in a SQL table from which permissions are assigned to each user.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using an old version of Dart and Flutter. This old version of the language is set so all variables can have a `null` value. On newer versions, you have to be specific and say for example `Rol? rol;`

This way the analyzer knows that this variable may be `null` and the call for the setter `idUser` inside your `AdministratorRolesAssignController.assignRol` should be written as `rol?.idUser = idUser;`

What this does is the following:

```dart
if (rol != null) {
  rol.idUser = user;
}
```

If you are sure that at that place the `rol` variable is not `null` then you could use `rol!.idUser = idUser` but only in newer versions of the language. I do suggest that you upgrade your versions since (I think so at least), when we reach the second semester in 2023, the older versions f the language such as this one will be unsupported. Just run `flutter upgrade` and you'll get the newest versions.